# VS 2019 don't delete files immediately

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I accidentally deleted a wrong file in Visual Studio 2019 before commiting the changes. I lost not a lot of work but I want to prevent this in future.
Can I setup VS 2019 somehow that files are not immediately deleted but kept in a cache for a while?
Supposedly there is already a backup folder which VS uses for deleted files, but this folder was empty in my case. And also the fact that VS moves files into the Windows bin doesn't help me because my repository is not on the system drive.

Do you know about any settings in VS or is there maybe an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for but this extension could help you. It migth not prevent the deletion, but give you the opportunity to recover the code.
I haven`t tested it and I am also not sure if it will work with VS2019.

A visual source code plugin for maintaining local history of files.

Every time you modify a file, a copy of the old contents is kept in the local history. At any time, you can compare a file with any older version from the history. It can help you out when you change or delete a file by accident. The history can also help you out when your workspace has a catastrophic problem. Each file revision is stored in a separate file inside the .history folder of your workspace directory (you can also configure another location, see local-history.path).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history

Answer (score -1):

The answer here is to use a version control system (like git) and keep a full history of your project.

Even on simple personal projects it is worth doing.

Comment: He uses a version control system, but he deleted the file before he committed the changes. So thats NOT the answer.